# How to Insert Multiple Array into Each Row in Database+php

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

You may refer my code [**here**.](http://pastebin.com/ptJi5Dzt)

I'm creating an invoice and doing testing on my `php`. 
From the code given above, my data will be like this:

Assuming `id_invoice` will be 1
and I have 2 rows of data consisting of items and quantity

from form:

```
id_ items | name    | quantity 
    1     | brake   |    2 
    2     | muffler |    1
```

So how do i insert this in to database like this? 
From my form I set it as array. I managed to get only 1 data inserted into the database.

Comment: Please post your code on this page so the question remains valid if the pastebin link does not at some point in time. Also, post not all of your code but only a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

it's because you call exit() function inside your loop, that function stops script

```
foreach($_POST['items'] as $row=>$itm)
{
   $itm2=mysql_real_escape_string($itm);
   $qty2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quantity'][$row]);

echo $sql="INSERT INTO invoiceinventory (id,id_invoic,id_invent,quantity_buy)VALUES('','1', '$itm2', '$qty2')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
exit(); //here you got serious problem


}
```

Comment: OMG @szapio ! it works great ! you are the best. didnt realized that. silly me. thank you !